# Erro ao chamar Java Script no HTML

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax

Ol, eu tô fazendo um content carregar outras páginas sem atualizar a masterpage com AJAX da seguinte forma:

Linha que eu clico

```
<li id="pag1">Pag1</li>
```

Script

```
$("#pag1").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
type :"POST",
 async: false,
 url: paginadeconteudo.php",
}).done(function(data){
    $("#conteudo").html(data); 
});
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aí tudo 100%, ele carrega a página dentro da outra, carrega os estilos e tudo, mas não carrega ou chama o Jquery. **Por exemplo na mascara em um campo X.**
**Se eu usar isso no cabeçalho da minha master page, o content não consegue executar, alguém sabe explicar o motivo?**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $("#cpf").mask("000.000.000-00");
    $("#tel, #tel2").mask("(00) 00000-0000");
</script>
```

EDITADO:
Esse é um exemplo do meu código. a Página que eu tô chamando n recebe o  mesmo se eu já referenciar diretamente dentro dela. Ela recebe se eu entrar na página e atualizar, mas se eu sair e voltar para de funcionar, é como se ref. não existisse.
obs.: Tente testar em uma páina .html local acho que o executar daqui tá bugou!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>teste</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .pagina {
      max-height: 200px;
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .menu {
      max-height: 200px;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
    

</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <button class="add-usuario">CHAMAR PAGINA</button>
  </div>
  <div class="pagina" id="conteudo"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="meudiretorio/meuajax.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(".add-usuario").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "https://www.doraziosportes.com.br/cadastrarusuario.php",
      }).done(function(data) {
        $("#conteudo").html(data);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está bem confusa, mas, em todas as páginas que utilizar jQuery você terá que  inserir os arquivos do jQuery, seguindo as posições **(1º - jQuery, 2º - plugins que utilizam jQuery**).

Comment: Obg, mas já fiz todas as referencias do jquery

Answer (score 0):

Colocar o script na pagina do seu conteúdo "paginadeconteudo.php", incluindo as bibliotecas mask, jquery, e dê o retorno:

```
echo '<script>
    $("#cpf").mask("000.000.000-00");
    $("#tel, #tel2").mask("(00) 00000-0000");
</script>';
```

Ja que você está usando jquery, indico mudar esse ajax pra isso:

```
<script>
    $(".add-usuario").click(function() {
      $.post('https://www.doraziosportes.com.br/cadastrarusuario.php', {dado: '1'}, function(data){
        $("#conteudo").html(data);
      })
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Obg, mas já fiz todas as referencias e não funfa.

Comment: Editei a resposta, cara tu tem que chamar esse script na outra página, ou carregar ele na função de callback, o script NÃO pode ser carregado antes do retorno da página de conteúdo.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta  da uma olhada.

Comment: Você precisa permitir que o arquivo seja acessado, coloca isso na primeira linha do codigo da tua pagina cadastrarusuario.php  " header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); "

Answer (score -2):

Tenta usar o load() do jquery, ou jogue as referencias no arquivo que esta carregando as outras paginas.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta  da uma olhada.